# Gradle 7 create a fat jar

Tags: java, gradle

I need to create a fat jar from my dependencies that won't contain dependencies in scope `compileOnly`

```
dependencies {
   api 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26' // this must be in the jar
   compileOnly 'it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:8.2.1' // this must not be in the jar

    jar {
        from {
            configurations.compileClasspath.findAll { it.name.endsWith('jar') }.collect { zipTree(it) }
        }
    }
}
```

When I build the project both dependencies are present within the final jar file. How am I supposed to exclude fastutil from fat jar?

I tried to use `runtimeOnly`

```
runtimeOnly 'it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:8.2.1' // this must not be in the jar
```

But this causes the fastutil to be unresolvable during compile time.

I'm running Java 16 and Gradle 7.0.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `configurations.runtimeClasspath` instead of `configurations.compileClasspath`. `compileClasspath` contains all libraries required for compilation, thus `fastutil` is included. `runtimeClasspath` on the other hand excludes libraries from configuration `compileOnly`.